# How to check file extension of selected file through askopenfilename in python

Tags: python, tkinter

i have problem regarding checking file extension. with askopenfilename we can select any type of file, but i only want *.jpg file, so i want to check if selected file is jpg or not.
I have tried this, but no result no error.

```
self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                              title="Select a File",
                                              filetypes = (("jpg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
self.splittedfilename = self.filename.split("/")

if self.splittedfilename[-1] == "*.jpg":
    print(self.filename)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `.endswith()` method for strings. You can simply use

```
if self.splittedfilename.endswith(".jpg"):
    print(self.filename)
else:
    pass
```

However, it is recommended to use `pathlib` when dealing with files, so this is probably better:

```
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path(self.filename)

if path.suffix == ".jpg":
    print(self.filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.splitext()` function.

Example:

```py
import os

splittedfilename = os.path.splitext("/path/to/fname.ext")
print(splittedfilename)
```

And the result is:

```
('/path/to/fname', '.ext')
```

So you can get the file extension by `splittedfilename[-1]`.